# How to execute WordPress/WooCommerce function from js/vue application

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js, woocommerce

The main problem is, that:
**I need to create a new, custom product in WooCommerce on the basis of the data which come from vue-web-component application. Then add this product to cart and make it purchasable.** 
I got an idea, that maybe it would be possible to execute a WooCommerce function on http request, then I could even pass the whole data via cookie.
I know how to create a new WooCommerce product via PHP function and I know how to add an existing product to cart via POST request. **The problem is to trigger a function**, which will receive data from the cookie or other way, when the button "add to cart" is pressed in the js-app.

*add existing product to cart: (may be useful)*

```
async function m_wc_add_to_cart( product_id ) {
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof wc_add_to_cart_params ) {
        // The add to cart params are not present.
        return false;
    }

    var product = new URLSearchParams();
    product.append('product_id', '43');
    product.append('quantity', '1');


    const endpoint = wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart' )

    console.log('endpoint', endpoint)

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }

    axios.post(
        endpoint, 
        product,
        config
    )
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        added_to_cart(response)         
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in WordPress, however I hope there won't be any rubbish down there ↓↓↓

I found out two solutions how to add a *newly created product to WooCommerce cart*. One of them is through **a callback of the custom endpoint**, the other one is through **an ajax request to the external PHP file**:

### Callback of the custom endpoint

When [registering a custom endpoint in WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/), one can define a function which will be executed after the request:

*functions.php*: 
(Registering custom endpoint in Wordpress. Callback defines a function, which is fired after the request)

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'my_own_namespace', 'my_own_route', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'my_own_function',
  ) );
} );
```

With *my_own_function* I create a new product and add it to cart (most of the code below comes from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code)):

*functions.php*: 
(Creating a new product via post insertion. Function fires as a callback)

```
function my_own_function(WP_REST_Request $request){

// Via post request I can send data (look at JS-code)
$price = $request['price'];

$post = array(
  'post_author' => $user_id,
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => "publish",
  'post_title' => 'Lorem ipsum...',
  'post_parent' => '',
  // "post_type => product" defines, that this post will be inserted as a product
  'post_type' => "product",
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );

if($post_id){
$attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
}

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Races', 'product_cat' );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '1');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', "");
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $price );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );

// file paths will be stored in an array keyed off md5(file path)
$downdloadArray =array('name'=>"Test", 'file' => $uploadDIR['baseurl']."/video/".$video);

$file_path =md5($uploadDIR['baseurl']."/video/".$video);


$_file_paths[  $file_path  ] = $downdloadArray;
// grant permission to any newly added files on any existing orders for this product
// do_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_file_download_paths', $post_id, 0, $downdloadArray );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable_files', $_file_paths);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_limit', '');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_expiry', '');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_download_type', '');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', '');

// add newly created product to cart
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $post_id );
};
```

Finally, from js-app I send an http request. Here I'm using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). The important thing is to pass arguments as a query string (using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)):

*footer.php*: 
(I placed script in *footer.php* file. Using axios I send an http request with data in the query-string form):

```
<script>
  async function runPHP(){
    var args = new URLSearchParams();
    args.append('price', '199');

    axios.post("your_wp_url/index.php/wp-json/my_own_namespace/my_own_route", args)
    .then(function (response) {
      // In case 'my_own_function' returned some value, the response will contain it
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
</script>

<button onclick="loadDoc()">Via Custom Endpoint</button>
```

### Ajax request to the external PHP file

Another solution is to create a PHP file with a request handler, which we send a request to.

I've created file *myActions.php* in theme's root folder, where I've placed an http request handler. There's also a WP function, which creates a new product and adds it to Woo cart. **NOTE: to make WP functions available in this file you need to load the wp-load.php file**:

*myActions.php*: 
(Newly created file with a request handler. To make WP functions available, one needs to load the wp-load.php file):

```
    //  wp-load.php makes WP functions available in this file
    define( 'WPPATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/wp-load.php' );
    require_once(WPPATH);

    function my_own_function($price){
        //... almost the same as in the previous example previous
    }

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action']; // action is past as a POST request prop
        $price = $_POST['price']; // same happens with optional arguments
        switch($action) {
            case 'test' : my_own_function($price);break;
        }
    }
```

Next, in the js-app I send an http request via axios:

*footer.php*: 
(I send an http POST request to the file *myActions.php*. In props I pass a function name and optional arguments):

```
    <script>
        // Here I define a path to 'myActions.php' file
        const myActionsUrl = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>'+'/myActions.php'

        var params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('action', 'my_own_function');
        params.append('price', '199');

        async function runPHP(){
            axios.post(myActionsUrl, params)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="runPHP()">Run myActions!</button>
```